# can you explain to me about using "@" in script php?

Tags: php

this code that i mean,

```
$ID=@$_POST['ID'];
```

Comment: It prevents a warning is the POST parameter is not available.

Comment: It's error control operator in php. More information on http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Comment: ok..thaks..Alexander O'Mara

Answer (score 0):

Using `@` suppresses error messages. You can find more explanation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php).